# Remove white Space on right side in Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, dygraphs

I'm developing a chart without legend or axis. In this chart I'm also drawing via the 2d context and the underlayCallback option.

The Problem I can not resolve is a mysterious white space on the right side of the chart (about 5px).

[image]

I modified a jsFiddle to represent the Problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/12magkox/

Dygraph Constructor for removing the legend and the axis:

```
legend: 'never',
    axes: {
      x: {drawGrid: true, drawAxis: false},
      y: {drawGrid: true, drawAxis: false}
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`rightGap`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#rightGap) option. Your estimate of "about" 5px looks to be spot-on!

> **rightGap**
>
> Number of pixels to leave blank at the right edge of the
> Dygraph. This makes it easier to highlight the right-most data point.
>
> Type: integer
>
> Default: 5